# fullcalendar jquery is not working for remote json feed

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

This is my code,

```
$('#calendar_div').fullCalendar({
header: {
                left: 'prev,next today',
                center: 'title',
                right: 'month,basicWeek,basicDay'
            },
            selectable: true,
            selectHelper: true,
            events:'/appt_get',
height: $("#calendar_div").height(),
         width: $("#calendar_div").width()-500,
editable: true,
});
```

this events are not displaying. but instead of the link infront of the events if i enter the data as below it works. This is the same data got from the the link.

```
[{"end": "2013-06-06 12:00:00", "title": "this is again a test", "start": "2013-06-06 09:00:00"}, {"end": "2013-06-09 14:59:11", "title": "testing this system", "start": "2013-06-09 14:14:11"}]
```